# How to decode mp4a-latm content in RTP using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, rtp, decoding, aac

I am trying to decode the mp4a-latm content using ffmpeg. I have used the CodecID as Codec_ID_AAC_LATM and extracted the config parameter from the SDP and further extracted the audio content from the RTP by removing the rtp header and sent it to decodeAudio4 function but the decode function always return the negative value.

I have gone through the RFC 3016 and the code of rtpdec_latm.c in ffmpeg src also but i am not able to find where i am doing the mistake and what exactly the procedure to send the content to decode.

As general, we need to send the config value frm SDP and then the raw audio packet form the RTP after removing the header but its not working.

Can someone help me in it?

Regards
Nitin

Comment: RFC 6416 also seems to be an extension but things are not clear in that too. i have got that the first byte after the RTP header says the size but if i send the leftover part to ffmpeg, it still returns negative value.